# Speed of python's "open(filepath)"

Tags: python, io

I'm currently writing a program that goes through a large directory of files and performs an action on each one. The core loop of my program looks like this (it's part of a class structure):

```
def processFile(self, path):
    handle = open(path)
    fileText = handle.read()
    result = #some program here, doesn't effect performance
    handle.close()
    print("Processed: {}".format(path))
    return result
```

Working through as many files as this does makes the program run slowly. However, if I issue an interrupt halfway through execution, and then run the program again, it processes the files that were already processed before the interrupt very quickly!

Is there a way to improve the speed of using open()?
Is there a reason why files that were processed in a previous execution of my program are processed instantly upon a second execution?

Also - I'm running this on Mac OSX 10.10.5

Comment: This might be because those files have been cached by your OS in RAM, unrelated to Python.

Comment: You could install and run a line profiler to be absolutely sure it's the open statement taking the time.

Comment: Having a large number of files in a directory usually has a huge impact on the performance of file I/O. Zou should start optimizing there.